# how to make the column editable in user defined datagrid in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to edit a particular column in particular row. I am using the below javascript:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arrDisplayRows.length; i++) {
    var ID = arrDisplayRows[i].getFieldByName("ID").getValue();
    if (ID == "aa") {
        arrDisplayRows[i].getFieldByName("Rate").setAttribute("isReadOnly", false);
    }
```

but this is not working. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below java script.It works fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrDisplayRows.length; i++) {
var ID = arrDisplayRows[i].getFieldByName("ID").getValue();
if (ID == "aa") {
    arrDisplayRows[i].getFieldByName("Rate").element.Readonly=true;

}
```

Comment: What is this class "TextBoxEditable"? Is it your own css?